# How can I reference a [non abstract] field of an object referred to by the class it's extending?

Tags: java, oop, abstract

That is, I have a list of class '`Entity`', which is an abstract class containing several different classes.
In the list, I can determine which are of a specific descendant classes using

```
if (list[i] instanceof Enemy)
```

However, I cannot, using the `list[i]` reference, reference fields which are specific to `Enemy` and not inherited.

Is there any simple way of grabbing a reference to it which will let me reference specific fields?

Otherwise I'll just rewrite that structure of the code.

Solved: Explicitly casting:

```
(Enemy)(list[i])
```

Comment: First of all, you grave an item from a List using list.get(i) in Java.
Second of all, your question is not very well formed. Can you please post the code and let us know how you're populating that list? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the element to the appropriate class.

```
Enemy enemy = (Enemy)element; 
int hitPoints = enemy.getHitPoints();
```

However, when working with a mixed collection of a base type, it is generally because you're only interested in the polymorphic behaviors, so I encourage you to follow through on at least exploring that particular area of your code. (On that note, it is also generally discouraged to access member fields or variables directly, as your question implies you wish to do, as that violates encapsulation.)

Answer (score 3):

you have to manually cast the object to `Enemy`:

```
((Enemy)(list[i])).enemyField
```

You may be able to leave out some of those paranthesis I'm never sure about that.

Also note that if you're doing a lot of casting, it may be a sign your design may need some improvement. Casting doesn't let you take advantage of the compiler's type safety features... can you hide the access to those fields through a method that's declared abstractly in the `Entity` class?

Answer (score 1):

If the object stored in your list is an instance of Enemy, you'll drop into your if statement, and you should be able to safely cast as:
`(Enemy) list[i]`

Answer (score 0):

If `someMethod` is a method in the `Enemy` class,

```
if( list[i] instanceof Enemy ){
  ((Enemy) list[i] ).someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" approach is to use generics:

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
...
enemies.add(new EnemySubClass()); // etc
...
for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
    enemy.someEnemyMethod();
}
```